# VBA: Target.Address effecting column before intended column

Tags: excel, vba

```
    'Require New Due Date Comment
    If Range(Target.Address).Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Provide Reason for New Due Date", vbOKOnly
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 1).Select
    End If
```

Hi all, hoping you can help, I'm a novice at VBA but have been until now successfully altering some code my boss asked me to for a template.  This one is stumping me though.  The code was written by someone no longer with the company.

I have a spreadsheet that has several columns, some of them locked down so that a user cannot enter, and others not so that a user can alter values on tasks that are pulled from a database.  This particular piece of code is supposed to pop up a message box when a date is entered into the New Due Date column.  Instead, it is popping up when I enter comments into the column before it (a cancel comments section).

I've tried designating the column in an additional if statement, but that merely turns off the popup altogether.

I have nearly the same exact logic for that cancel comments section and it works fine.  However, it is able to have an additional qualifier of another cell being equal to the value of "cancelled" to draw off of.  The above occurrence also can only happen if that cell is listed as cancelled, but it is not required if the task is cancelled so it shouldn't pop up every time the task is canceled.

Thanks in advance!

ETA:  Forgot to say, it worked as intended until I added another column to the sheet at the request of my manager.  I figured with it not designating a specific range it would be ok.

Comment: `Target` is a range in itself - you should be able to just use `If Target<> "" Then`

Comment: Is this code in a `Method` or a UDF? Can you provide the full code as I suspect that you probably have the code in the wrong method

Comment: Also - what event is this in?  If it's a `SelectionChange` event then the act of selecting the `Offset` cell will fire the event again (you'd need `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the code and `Application.EnableEvents = True` after it _and_ if an error occurs).

Comment: It's in a private sub.  I unfortunately can't provide all of the code because of confidentiality.  In the VBA Project itself, it's under the Microsoft Excel Objects on the tasks sheet.   There is one line of code indented above it a bit saying "  Range(Target.Address).Select  ''''DO NOT DELETE, PREVENTS LOOP"                                                                        Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  There was a section of code further up referencing the wrong column (was O before).  Thanks everyone!

```
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P14:P1437")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo PError:

    If InStr(1, Target.Address, ":", 1) > 0 Then

    GoTo PError

    End If
```

Comment: It looks like `If InStr(1, Target.Address, ":", 1) > 0 Then` is just checking if more than one cell is being referenced by looking for `:` in the address.  Would be better to use `If Target.Cells.Count>1 Then`.

Comment: Also `GoTo PError` doesn't raise an error.  Maybe better to use `Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "WorkSheet_Change","More than one cell selected."` and the `On Error Goto PError` will kick in.

Comment: Gotcha, I will implement these suggestions, thank you!